# Footer doesn't display in page.php

Tags: pages, footer

So I'm trying to integrate static HTML/CSS/JS into WordPress and everything goes really well, but now I realised that my footer isn't displaying in my individual static pages (page.php). But I can see my footer in front (index) page and in my custom contact form page.

This is my page.php file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- Page Content-->
    <div id="content" class="snap-content">

                <div class="header-clear"></div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="container no-bottom">

                            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                            <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I also have index.php and front-page.php files (both have `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>` functions).

And yes, in my footer.php I'm calling `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` right before the closing  tag.

Appreciate any help.

EDIT: I've tried a lot of different variations and wirte some dummy static html content inside page.php, but whatever I do and change, I can't make footer appear.

**EDIT 2:** Why it's happening? [image]

Comment: Enable Debug mode by using `define('WP_DEBUG',true);` in wp-config.php and post any errors that you encountered.

Comment: I added this line in my wp-config.php and there was no such file. So I created it manually and installed "Log Viewer" plug-in and it's absolutelly empty. I set my permissions to 777 (for testing) - still empty.
I've also tried to create php-errors.log file and it's empty too. So, as I understand, where are no errors.

Comment: I have edited the main thread (EDIT 2).

Comment: `Why it's happening?` Can you elaborate what's happening since footer is displayed there.

Comment: I mean I was very "surprised" to see footer at the top of the page. I wrote a solution to this problem to another users answer. Thank you, Manor, for your collaboration with my problem :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `include("footer.php");`

And I see your

```
<div id="content" class="snap-content">
```

didn't have close tag `</div>`

Comment: It actually has its closing tag, since `<div class="header-clear"></div>` is in the same line, so 3 closes.

The reason to this was that I DIDN'T needed that last </div> tag, which closes the `<div id="content" class="snap-content">` because it's being closed inside footer.php file. 

Thank you for your answers. You gave me an idea where my problem could be :)